# Convert a string that has '√' to one than can be given to eval();

Tags: javascript

I have a function that receives a string like `'5 + 10 * 4'` and then evaluates it with `eval(string)` returning the result. The code works but I'm having an issue, sometimes the string can have a `'√'` value; ex:  `'4 * √64 + 10'`. This makes the `eval()` function crash. How can I convert `'4 * √64 + 10'`  to `'4 * Math.sqrt(64) + 10'`.

Comment: use regex......

Answer (score 1):

First things first, be careful that your `eval` isn't allowed to execute arbitrary, unsanitized JavaScript. XSS attacks can be very nasty.

Second, use a regex.

```js
function solve(math) {
  return Number(eval(math.replace(/√(\d+)/g, 'Math.sqrt($1)')));
}

console.log(solve('4 * √64 + 10'));
```

If you need to be able to also take the square root of arbitrarily nested expressions, you will need an actual parser, in which case you should probably use a library which is equipped to also evaluate the parsed math expressions, like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html).